# Have some reason to create one function for input, to "uptimize code and memory"?

Tags: python

I am a BEGINNER, I’m just trying to find out, although I guess that there’s really no point, but I don’t know much.
Does it make sense to create a function for input, will there be any benefit from this?
I have more than 10 inputs and I can not reduce the number, so it occurred to me.

```
def up_input(inp_text, input_type):
    if len(inp_text) == 0:
        inp_text = 'Enter here: '
    this_is_input = input(inp_text)
    if input_type == 1:
        return int(this_is_input)
    else:
        return this_is_input
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain what you are trying to do.
Of course, a function is a good way for not repeating your code, but you can be able to do what you want using a different method. For example, getting a list of elements and parsing them (instead of asking 10 times for an element) or using the argparse library and asking for arguments when calling your program.

Comment: ineractive, some crypto script for lesson, just make it for easy understanding)i know that better make code bot repeatable, but, is have some useful thing for memory. just any way, it looks like the same, if it will be input.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want to do.
Anyway, one thing you should notice is that there is not much sense for checking if inp_text is of len 0.  You would probably be better by
def up_input(input_type,inp_text= None)
and then check if inp_text is None.
In this case, You can just not pass the inp_text if you want the default behavior, as opposed to what you did that makes you pass "" if you want the default